# Hide IP and Port when Connecting to Server

Tags: node.js, socket.io, client

I am designing a website which uses a node server and socket.io as a middle man between the server and client. As far as I am aware, the only way to connect the client socket.io to the server is to write a line of code like the following:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://SERVER_IP:PORT");
```

With the obvious substitutions. I may be wrong in thinking this, but having this information on client code for all to see seems like a serious security risk. I was wondering if this actually the case, that there may be serious issues posed by displaying this information; if so, how would I go about not having it displayed on client code, since the client has to have some method of connecting to the server. I've looked into proxy ip's, but saw it only in php and didn't know if socket had another way of dealing with this.

Comment: Why do you think it would be a "serious security risk?"

Comment: I am very new to web design and client/server communication so I could be very wrong, but my logic was that if someone got the ip to the server, they could get into the server themselves somehow.

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think the client  is not the best place to hide things,  may be you should assume that the attackers knows everything about your service and write your websocket server with care on the server side.

Comment: Visitors already have the IP of your web server. They could hack that too unless the web server is well designed and well protected. The same goes for socket.io or any other kind of server.

Comment: Thank you to you both for helping me realize where I need to focus my attention, and solving my concerns

Comment: Normally, you would just do a socket.io back to the same server that the web page came from and you can do that with just this: `var socket = io.connect();`.